# How important is server-side statelessness in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, stateless

In our single page AngularJS application, we have the option to choose an employee, and this chosen employee is saved in the $rootScope. There are many requests across the application within models to retrieve objects from the server, that among other parameters, send the information about the chosen employee in order to get the data belonging to that one.

I have a task to move the information about the chosen employee into the server and update this field in the server every time it's changed on the client side. After that, the models would not need to add this information when requesting data from the server, and the server would know which employee is chosen and return that person's objects only.

My intuition says this is a very bad idea, but I couldn't find a source to prove that. The obvious advantage would be the removal of javascript code that retrieves the chosen employee and sends it to the server with every request, as well as a slight network optimization because of the reduced package size of the requests with that removed parameter. On the other hand, it doesn't feel right to respond differently to the exact same request with small intervals in case the chosen employee was changed. Another problem is that in the most common implementation, the session is kept in only one server, which would make things more difficult in case the application is split across multiple servers. Last but not least, I feel it increases the chances of an inconsistent state between the server and the application and therefore getting incorrect responses from the server.

Is this transition really more like asking for trouble or is it worth reducing the overhead with this approach? Apart from opinions, I would appreciate a clear source that I can use as a proof. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you sending the whole employee to the server to get information about it? Can't you just send an ID? It sounds like there _is_ a problem with your current design, but the proposed solution is not the answer.

Comment: Obviously I am just sending an ID, this has nothing to do with the question, so I didn't give much detail there.

Comment: Sure seems like it has everything to do with the question: _"The obvious advantage would be the removal of javascript code that retrieves the chosen employee and sends it to the server with every request, as well as a slight network optimization because of the reduced package size of the requests with that removed parameter"_ If you're just sending an ID, I don't see what the problem is. You're fixing a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: Retrieving an ID from the rootscope in many different parts of the application in order to add it into various requests is unnecessary code duplication if the server can maintain that information to begin with. I also think it's not worth the change, but I'm not after opinions, I want some sort of proof that shows what measures are reasonable in order to keep the server (more) stateless.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is right. It is a bad idea to have the edit state on server side. The basic rule is to keep it simple. In your case keeping the state on the client is simple and clear. If the edit it ready, send all information to the server and handle the post.

The code to handle server and client side state is complex and has many error paths, like session timeouts, forward and backward, etc. This will results in errors or unexpected edit results.

[why-we-abandoned-server-generated-web-pages](http://johnmunsch.com/2014/02/22/why-we-abandoned-server-generated-web-pages/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's useful, but not exactly what I'm looking for.